# Is my fridge not cooling because of this fan?

Tags: refrigerator

I'm trying to fix a fridge/freezer that recently stopped working but still has power. I removed the panel from the freezer and there was a lot of ice build up which I let defrost. I noticed that the little fan which (I think) forces cold air into the fridge seems a bit wonky. It sometimes starts running if I give is a spin to get it started but then stops shortly after. This video shows that: https://youtu.be/ZQMJDpgACQc. Is this "abnormal", or should I look for the source of the problem elsewhere?

Comment: a bad fan would be my first guess. it's a moving part, and you've seen it misbehave.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. The fridge is cooled by running refrigerator air through the freezer compartment; that fan is responsible for making the air exchange happen. If the freezer still cools fine while the fridge doesn't then the fan is a likely culprit. There could also be a problem in whatever electronics control the fan, but start with replacing the fan only.